# Slider hover out

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a slider which works however I'm trying to get the slider to continue when the mouse leaves the `<li>` image.

It does stop when the mouse enters using the `.hover()` method - but it doesn't continue on once the mouse moves off the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        // settings
        var $slider = $('.home-slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
        var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
        var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
        var $time_between_slides = 5000; // 5 seconds

        function slides() {
            return $slider.find($slide);
        }

        slides().fadeOut();

        // set active classes
        slides().first().addClass('active');
        slides().first().fadeIn(100);

        // auto scroll
        $interval = setInterval(function () {
            var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

            slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
            slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

            if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

            slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
            slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
        }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);

        $('.home-slider').hover(function () {
            $interval = clearInterval($interval);
        }, function () {
            interval = setInterval($transition_time, $time_between_slides);
        });

        $('home-slider').mouseout(function () {
            slides().fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have an error in your code, the line : `$('home-slider').mouseout(function () {` should be :  `$('.home-slider').mouseout(function () {`. Renamed the selector from `home-slider` to be `.home-slider`

Comment: Thanks for that little error - still doesn't continue the slide after the mouse has left "the building" :-)

Comment: Why do you handle the `mouseout` event as well as the `hover` event? One will most likely be overriding the other. Try removing the MouseOut event handler and see if it works.

Comment: The hover stops the slider from progressing, the mouseout event in theory should continue the slider once the mouse has left. I removed the mouseout and the slider doesn't continue to "slide"

Comment: The mouseout event only fades out the elements found by the `slides()` function, why would you expect this to continue the slider?

Comment: I'm learning as I code, so I thought the slide would continue if I called it once the hover out would occur.

Comment: I think you might be confused about how the slider works. Can you show your code for the `flip` function you use?

Comment: ha ha - thats another error - had initially thought of a flip to happen once the mouse had left. I've pulled it off and replace with this:$transition_time, $time_between_slides

Comment: The line `interval = setInterval($transition_time, $time_between_slides);` is not valid as you are not passing a function for the interval to call.

Comment: so I would need to pass a function instead of a variable?

Comment: Yes otherwise the interval will not be executing any code and is therefore pointless.

Comment: have tried adding: $interval = setInterval($interval); and it doesn't work, $interval can be called if its outside the scope of the function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restructured your code to work correctly.

What I have done is to move the Settings and Individual functions outside the `jQuery(function($) { ... });`. I have modified the first setInterval to use the `sliderInterval` function and also the `hover` event to use this same function.

I've also removed the `mouseout` event handler as I don't think it was necessary.

The code should now work as follows :

1. Automatically slides through elements on page load
2. Sliding stops when one of the slides is hovered over
3. Sliding continues once the mouse has left the slide.

<kbd>[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/KTXKv/)</kbd>

Code :

```
    // settings
    var $slider = $('.home-slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 5000; // 5 seconds

    jQuery(function ($) {
        slides().fadeOut();

        // set active classes
        slides().first().addClass('active');
        slides().first().fadeIn(100);

        // auto scroll
        $interval = setInterval(sliderInterval, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);

        $('.home-slider').hover(function () {
            $interval = clearInterval($interval);
        }, function () {
            $interval = setInterval(sliderInterval, $time_between_slides);
        });
    });

    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    function sliderInterval() {
        var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

        slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
        slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

        if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

        slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
        slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - it works as intended, can I ask why the mouseout event was not needed?

Comment: All the mouseout event was doing was hiding the elements, it was not re-starting the interval. Whereas the second function in the hover event now is. So it was not required.

Comment: ok, I see now what you mean, will take some time to understand, but thanks again for your help.